# Options for dynamic properties in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have an application with some externalized configuration in the form of properties. I would like the application to react to a change of such properties without a restart or full context refresh.

I am not clear what my options are.

Artificial example: the application implements a service that receives requests and decides whether to queue or reject them. The maximum size of the queue is a property.

```
final int queueMaxSize = queueProperties.getMaxSize();
if (queue.size() >= queueMaxSize) { //reject }
```

Where `QueueProperties` is a class annotated with @ConfigurationProperties.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.limits.queue")
@Getter
@Setter
public class QueueProperties {
  public int maxSize = 10;
}
```

This works as far as allowing me to control behavior via system properties, profiles, etc.
**However, I would like to be able to change this value without releasing/deploying/restarting/refreshing the application.**

My application already uses [Archaius](https://www.baeldung.com/netflix-archaius-spring-cloud-integration).
If I push a new value for this property using our internal infrastructure, i can see the application Spring Environment does receive the new value.
(e.g., `/admin/env` reflects the value and changes dynamically).

The part I'm not clear on is: **how to make my service react to the change of value in the environment?**

I found two ways, but they seem hairy, I wonder if there are better options. I expected this to be a common problem with a first class solution in the Spring ecosystem.

*Hacky solution #1:*

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.limits.queue")
QueueProperties queueProperties() {
    return new QueueProperties();
}
```

And inject this into the service using the properties as `Provider<QueueProperties>` and use it as `queuePropertiesProvider.get().getMaxSize()`.

This works but has a few side-effects I'm not a fan of:

- `ConfigurationProperties` annotation moved from the class to the bean definition
- A new `QueueProperties` object is created and bound to values for every request coming in
- Provider might throw on `get()`
- Invalid values are not detected until the first request comes in

*Hacky solution #2:*

Don't annotate my properties class with `ConfigurationProperties`, inject the Spring environment at construction time. Implement the getters as such:

```
int getMaxSize() {
   return environment.getProperty("myapp.limits.queue", 10);
}
```

This also works ok in terms of behavior. However
 - This is not annotated as property (unlike the rest of the properties classes in this large project, makes it harder to find)
 - This class does not show up in `/admin/configprops`

*Hacky solution #3:*

Schedule a recurring task that uses `Environment` to update my singleton `QueueProperties` bean.

Any further ideas/suggestions/pointers?
Is there a canonical/recommended way to do this that does not have the shortcoming of my solutions above?